# Output information to spreadsheet through Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, spreadsheet, code-cleanup

I've got a cleanup script that I'm intending to use to clean hundreds of virtual servers through the use of active directory. In the past I would create a simple .txt file that would display the following:

-Amount of disk space that existed before the script was run

-How much space after it was run

-Total space cleared

In the past this worked great, however it was intended to be used on a single server at a time rather than hundreds. Since I'm wanting to change towards running this script on hundreds of scripts at once, I'd like to change this to a spreadsheet which would display the same data as well as show the name of each server that the script was ran against.

How could I manage to create this type of output in a spreadsheet format and display that? Here's my current code (the .txt method):

```
$logFilePath = "C:\logfile.txt"
$disks = Get-WMIObject -Computer $server -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID like '%C%'"
$beforeFreeSpace = $disks.FreeSpace
$beforeFreeSpaceMB = [math]::truncate($beforeFreeSpace / 1MB)

$preCleanupMessage = "Space available before cleanup ran (MB): "
$preCleanupMessage += $beforeFreeSpaceMB
$preCleanupMessage | out-file -filePath $logFilePath -Append

$afterFreeSpace = $disks.FreeSpace
$afterFreeSpaceMB = [math]::truncate($afterFreeSpace / 1MB)

$freedSpace = "Freed up space after cleanup (MB): "
$freedSpace += $afterFreeSpaceMB - $beforeFreeSpaceMB

$freedSpace | out-file -filePath $logFilePath -Append
$message = "Free space remaining after cleanup (in MB): "
$message += [math]::truncate($afterFreeSpace / 1MB)
$message | out-file -filePath $logFilePath -Append
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
$Servers = "server1","server2"
$logFileCollection = @()

$servers | % {
    Write-Host Working on $_
    $server = $_
    $disk = Get-WMIObject -Computer $server -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID like '%C%'"
    $beforeFreeSpaceMB = [math]::truncate($disk.FreeSpace / 1MB)
    #DO SOME WORK HERE TO FREE UP SPACE
    $logFileCollection += New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        beforeFreeSpaceMB = $beforeFreeSpaceMB
        afterFreeSpaceMB = [math]::truncate($disks.FreeSpace / 1MB)
        freedSpace = [math]::truncate($disks.FreeSpace / 1MB) - $beforeFreeSpaceMB
    }
}

$logFileCollection | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "C:\logCSV.csv"
```

Also, keep in mind that the default gwmi cmdlet can time out and you may have to work around that.  Good luck.  Also, run this manually and if you have to abort the script at any point, simply run the last line to get the output up to that point.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the advice! One thing concerning what you said about running this manually, do you know how frequently the default gwmi time out? I'm planning to eventually work towards making this script run automated.

Comment: It depends on your environment.   Maybe all of your servers are healthy.  Mine never were.  Try this: http://blog.usepowershell.com/2009/01/dealing-with-wmi-timeouts/  - also, you may want to throw a If (test-connection $_ -quiet) { type check in there before letting it start the WMI check.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something like this that runs against 1700 VMs. I had a look at all my options and immediately ruled out two of them:

- PowerCLI (the VMware PowerShell Module) because I wanted my script to work across Hyper-Visors.
- WMI (Get-WMIObject) It is too unreliable. Its really hit and miss.

So I decided to use invoke-command:

```
$VMList = "server1","server2"
$MachineInfo = @()

foreach($VM in $VMList)
{
   $MachineInfo += Invoke-Command $VM{
   $obj = New-Object PSObject
   $Drive = Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Name -eq "C"}
   $beforeFreeSpace = $Drive.Free
   $beforeFreeSpaceMB = [Math]::Round(($Drive.Free /1024) /1024)
   $obj | Add-Member -Name "BeforeFreeSpace" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $beforeFreeSpaceMB

   ## Clean Up Over Here

   $Drive = Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Name -eq "C"}
   $afterFreeSpace = $Drive.Free
   $afterFreeSpaceMB = [Math]::Round(($Drive.Free /1024) /1024)
   $obj | Add-Member -Name "AfterFreeSpace" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $afterFreeSpaceMB

   $freedSpace = $obj.AfterFreeSpace - $obj.BeforeFreeSpace
   $obj | Add-Member -Name "FreedSpace" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $freedSpace

   return $obj}
}

$MachineInfo | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "C:\log.csv"
```

Been working great for about 2 months now, also I modified the version I posted to only check your C:\ drive  if you want to check all drives a just leave a comment an ill modify it.

Comment: Hi Taylor, since I plan on running this on plenty of servers, this is exactly what I want in order to avoid timeouts. One question though, is your code going through each server one by one (due to using a foreach) or is there a method to make it go through all VMs at once? The bulk of my code when ran takes a good 20-30 mins to run and if it has to go through several hundred servers weekly (planning to automate this) then it'll take extremely long to finish running.

Comment: Well, this script was written in PowerShell 2. So at the moment you are correct it iterates through each server. There are really two options here, if you need to use PowerShell 2 you can use the -AsJob parameter that will just spawn a new thread for each VM which might be a bit crazy if you running it against 1000 servers for example. This is currently a limitation of PowerShell. However PowerShell v3 introduces Workflows which allow you to execute your scripts in parallel as well as checkpoint them in case you need to reboot! I would think you need to use PowerShell 2 though, if so

Comment: let me know and if you upvote me ill try modify my script as best i can to help you out :)

Comment: Thanks Taylor! I'm using Powershell 2 at the moment so I was aware of the current limitations. I haven't heard about the -AsJob parameter before, however I'll look into that (in any case out of curiosity :-) ).

Comment: Also one thing, while testing this out I noticed that for some reason the spreadsheet that gets created is completely empty. I'm unaware of why, however $MachineInfo doesn't really fill up with anything.

Comment: Hey i fixed it, used the pipeline to to add objects to the array, please mark me as the answer if it works for you.